# Run SqlCeEngine.Upgrade on SDF-File (created with MSSQL 2005) after upgrading to MSSQL 2008

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

Im trying to programmatically convert a `SDF-File` from `3.0` to `3.5`.
Code looks like this:

```
Dim engine As New SqlCeEngine(strMyValidConnectionString)
engine.Upgrade()
```

And the error message I am getting looks like this:

> The file that is being referenced is not a valid SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition (version 3.1) or SQL Server 2005 Mobile Edition (version 3.0) database file to perform upgrade

I am using `VS2005`, my Windows Form Application is being compiled to a `WM 6.5` device.
The `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` is version `3.5.1.0` an being taken from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: before this gets buried: anybody?

Comment: Pull the sdf file form the device, and check with my SQL CE Toolbox, that the file is a valid 3.0/3.1 file.